# How to use webp-converter (npm module) in react?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-hooks, node-modules, image-formats

I have used [webp-converter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webp-converter)  node.js module to convert image formats. I tested this with nodejs in the console. It works. But how do I use this module in react?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tried to use it in my React project and it turns out the module is trying to do a [system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exec_(system_call)) with `exec()` which does not work on the client-side. This leads me to believe that this module is only for usecases where the conversion would happen at the server-side. So the answer is: You can't.